# Probability density histogram with unequal bin widths

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics, histograms

I am confused by output of `Histogram` and `HistogramList` for probability density (`"PDF"`) when bin widths are not equal.

According to [this](https://www.princeton.edu/~achaney/tmve/wiki100k/docs/Histogram.html) and [this](http://www.geog.ucsb.edu/~joel/g210_w07/lecture_notes/lect04/oh07_04_1.html) pages and other sources, density histograms are computed by dividing counts by bar widths and **total** number of observations. But `Histogram` obviously uses another algorithm as one can see from the following example:

```
SeedRandom[1];
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 15];
HistogramList[data, {{-2, 0, 1}}, "PDF"][[2]]
BinCounts[data, {{-2, 0, 1}}]/((Length[data] - 3) Differences[{-2, 0, 1}])
```

> {1/6, 2/3}
>
> {1/6, 2/3}

The outputs are identical when bin counts are divided by total number of observations **minus 3** in this case. Why is it? What algorithm `Histogram` uses for determining this difference (in other cases I got other numbers)?

**An addition**

Rod has answered the original question but there is another issue: if one gives upper bin boundary equal to the upper datapoint value then this value will be excluded from the histogram. It does not contradict the documentation where stated that `{{b1,b2,...}}` will `use the bins [b1,b2),[b2,b3),...`. Here is an illustration:

```
HistogramList[data, {{-2, 0, Max[data] - 10^-13}}, 
   "PDF"][[2]] - HistogramList[data, {{-2, 0, Max[data]}}, "PDF"][[2]]
HistogramList[data, {{-2, 0, Max[data] + 10^-13}}, "PDF"][[2]] - 
 HistogramList[data, {{-2, 0, Max[data]}}, "PDF"][[2]]
```

> {0, 2.99205*10^-14}
>
> {-(1/105), 0.0123342}

One can see that subtraction of `10^-13` does not alter the result significantly as expected but addition of `10^-13` changes it considerably because now the point `Max[data]` is included in the histogram. One can check this directly:

```
HistogramList[data, {{-2, 0, Max[data]}}, "PDF"][[2]]
BinCounts[data, {{-2, 0, Max[data]}}]/ 
  Differences[{-2, 0, Max[data]}]/(Length[data] - 1)

HistogramList[data, {{-2, 0, Max[data] + 10^-13}}, "PDF"][[2]]
BinCounts[data, {{-2, 0, Max[data] + 10^-13}}]/ 
  Differences[{-2, 0, Max[data]}]/Length[data]
```

> {1/7, 0.462531}
>
> {1/7, 0.462531}
>
> {2/15, 0.474865}
>
> {2/15, 0.474865}

Comment: Using `SeedRandom[1]` you get 3 observations higher than 1. When you use `Histogram[data,{{-2,0,1}}]` you're excluding those 3 observations...

Comment: @Rod I just checked, yes. But does it matter?

Comment: It does matter when you're computing PDF's. If you exclude those 3 observations, now your probability (i.e., "PDF") should be based on 12 observations, and not 15...

Comment: @Rod Thank you for clarification. You may post it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `SeedRandom[1]` you get 3 observations higher than 1. When you use `Histogram[data,{{-2,0,1}}]` you're excluding those 3 observations...

If you exclude those 3 observations, now your probability (i.e., "PDF") should be based on 12 observations, and not 15...

Answer (score 0):

Alexey,

Histogram probability is based on **Area and BinCounts**, and not on BinCounts alone...

If you use `Max[data]` you'll get

> 1.5443

So the **area** of your histogram will be computed untill 1.5443. (Try yourself: compare `Histogram[data, {{-2, 0, Max[data]}},"PDF"]` and `Histogram[data, {{-2, 0, Max[data]}}]`).

If you use `Length[data]` you'll get

> 15

So the **area** of your histogram will be computed untill 15. (Try yourself: compare `Histogram[data, {{-2, 0, Length[data]}},"PDF"]` and `Histogram[data, {{-2, 0, Length[data]}}]`).

That's why you should set the max value for you Histogram...

Comment: I think you misunderstand my second question. The point is the difference between `HistogramList[data, {{-2, 0, Max[data]}}, "PDF"]` and `HistogramList[data, {{-2, 0, Max[data] + 10^-13}}, "PDF"]`. Obviously adding `10^-13` cannot alter the result significantly (one can verify this by subtracting `10^-13`). The reason for the difference is that in the second case the value `Max[data]` **is included** in the histogram while in the first case it is not. I do not understand why it is not included in the first case.

Comment: When you add `10^-13` to one block of the histogram, you are, at the same time, "removing" slightly the probability of the other blocks... That's why you get the difference... Anyway I think, too, that the difference is considerable...

Comment: Compare `HistogramList[data, {{-2, 0, Max[data] - 10^-13}}, "PDF"][[2]] - 
 HistogramList[data, {{-2, 0, Max[data]}}, "PDF"][[2]]` with `HistogramList[data, {{-2, 0, Max[data] + 10^-13}}, "PDF"][[2]] - 
 HistogramList[data, {{-2, 0, Max[data]}}, "PDF"][[2]]`. The huge difference in the second case is due to included point `Max[data]` while in other cases it is discarded.