# How do I create a histogram with unequal bin widths?

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics

I would like to create a histogram for human population by age, but the $2010$ census data I have available is for five uneven cohorts: ages $0$-$17$, $18$-$24$, $25$-$44$, $45$-$64$, and $65+$. My county has the following data: `{86031, 26671, 91927, 93983, 32232}`, for a total population of $330844$. The corresponding histogram bins should have widths `{17, 7, 20, 20, 20}` and heights `{86031/17, 26671/7, 91927/20, 93983/20, 32232/20}`. I will eventually want to make this pretty by adding labels, etc., but I don't see how to even get started.

Comment: The second argument of the `Histogram` function directly specifies the bins to use. `Histogram[{x1,x2},bspec]` plots a histogram with bin width specification `bspec`.

Comment: Related: "[Probability density histogram with unequal bin widths](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/24344/280)."

Answer (score 9):

Based solely on the information provided IMO you need to use `RectangleChart`. I'm not sure how to create the histogram you desire using `Histogram` and **only** the information in your question

[image]

-- here is the `RectangleChart` implementation:

```
{widths, totals} = {{17, 7, 20, 20, 20}, {86031, 26671, 91927, 93983, 
   32232}}; 
RectangleChart[Transpose@{widths, totals/widths}]
```

[image]

You can make this pretty:

```
RectangleChart[Transpose@{widths, totals/widths},
 BarSpacing -> 2,
 ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[Dashed],
 ChartElementFunction -> "FadingRectangle", 
 ChartLabels -> {"0-17", "18-24", "25-44", "45-64", "65+"}, 
 ChartStyle -> ColorData["Charting"],
 BaseStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Arial", 12],
 PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

The natural way is to use `RectangleChart` since your data is already processed.

I will just show how to use `Histogram` for your purposes, it requires step back to create the data, that's why Mike's solution is better.

```
data = {{{0, 17}, {17, 24}, {24, 44}, {44, 64}, {64, 84}}, 
        {86031, 26671, 91927, 93983, 32232}};

dat = RandomReal[#, Round[#2/Abs[Subtract @@ #]]] & @@@ Transpose[data];

Histogram[dat, {{0, 17, 24, 44, 64, 84}}]
```

[image]

Comment: I guess thats what I meant in my answer. The data presented in the question is already binned/aggregated so `Histogram` is the wrong choice in this instance unless you go backwards first.

Comment: The RectangleChart approach Mike Honeychurch proposes is certainly more in keeping with my Mathematica skills.  Kuba's solution — apparently by generating random data in the proper bins in the proper amounts to create the desired histogram — is awesome, but beyond my ability!

Answer (score 8):

Alternatively you can fix both the bin end points and their heights explicitly. I've set 120 as a reasonable endpoint for the last bin. The zero in the input data is just there as a place holder and is effectively ignored.

```
Histogram[{0}, {{0, 18, 25, 45, 65, 120}}, {86031/17, 26671/7, 
   91927/20, 93983/20, 32232/20} &]
```

[image]

I would use the rectangle chart approach as others have suggested but this at least gives a way to use the height function to do what you are wanting without resorting to sampling.

Obviously if you want to label the axis differently you can use `Ticks`.

```
Histogram[{0}, {{0, 18, 25, 45, 65, 120}}, {86031/17, 26671/7, 
   91927/20, 93983/20, 32232/20} &, 
     Ticks -> {{{(0 + 17)/2, "0-17"}, {(18 + 24)/2, "18-24"}, {(25 + 44)/
        2, "25-44"}, {(45 + 64)/2, "45-64"}, {(65 + 120)/2, "65+"}}, Automatic}]
```

[image]